# Top menu showing a blank option which redirects me to an undefined page. How can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a blog site which has some issues. When you will try to open my blog in a smartphone or zoom it to 300%, you will see the top menu turn into a drop-down menu which has a blank option on the second place of it. When anyone clicks it, it redirects to a 404 Error Page. Please help me to fix this error.

I am attaching some images for reference.

[Screenshot showing menu without blank option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCqOL.png)

[Screenshot showing menu with blank option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MLMx.png)

[Screenshot showing 404 Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuRnn.png)

I will also add the menu bar code with it.

> // Plugin: SelectNav.js ~ url: https://github.com/lukaszfiszer/selectnav.js
>   window.selectnav=function(){"use strict";var e=function(e,t){function c(e){var t;if(!e)e=window.event;if(e.target)t=e.target;else if(e.srcElement)t=e.srcElement;if(t.nodeType===3)t=t.parentNode;if(t.value)window.location.href=t.value}function h(e){var t=e.nodeName.toLowerCase();return t==="ul"||t==="ol"}function p(e){for(var t=1;document.getElementById("selectnav"+t);t++);return e?"selectnav"+t:"selectnav"+(t-1)}function d(e){a++;var t=e.children.length,n="",l="",c=a-1;if(!t){return}if(c){while(c--){l+=o}l+=" "}for(var v=0;v"+l+g+"";if(s){var b=e.children[v].children[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCqOL.png);if(b&&h(b)){n+=d(b)}}}}if(a===1&&u){n=''+u+""+n}if(a===1){n=''+n+""}a--;return n}e=document.getElementById(e);if(!e){return}if(!h(e)){return}if(!("insertAdjacentHTML"in window.document.documentElement)){return}document.documentElement.className+=" js";var n=t||{},r=n.activeclass||"active",i=typeof n.autoselect==="boolean"?n.autoselect:true,s=typeof n.nested==="boolean"?n.nested:true,o=n.indent||"-",u=n.label||"Menu",a=0,f=" selected ";e.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend",d(e));var l=document.getElementById(p());if(l.addEventListener){l.addEventListener("change",c)}if(l.attachEvent){l.attachEvent("onchange",c)}return l};return function(t,n){e(t,n)}}();

Comment: Removing pub links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this script to your website. I tested with chrome debug tool and it worked.

When you resize browser or use in ipad/iphone, it will trigger code to remove options have undefined

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width()< 992){
      $('.selectnav option').each(function(index,item){ 
        if($(item).val() == "undefined"){ $(this).remove();}
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, I tried pasting the code in my template but it did not work, maybe because I pasted it at a wrong place. Can you please tell me where I should paste it?

Comment: you can F12 and paste this script to console it worked

Comment: Ok. Let me try.

Comment: Thank you, sir, the code is actually working with the console. I will figure out where I have to place it. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again for your support.